# Spotify Web API Authorization not giving correct response

Tags: php, laravel, api, spotify

I'm trying to implement Authorization from the Spotify Web API.

I'm using Postman to review the requests. At the first step of the Authorization process, I don't get the desired response.
I'm using GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize endpoint with 3 parameters: 
`client_id`, `response_type` and `redirect_uri` , but so far I get the following response:

```json
{
    "phoneFeatureEnabled": false,
    "user": false,
    "BON": [
        "0",
        "0",
        220165699
    ]
}
```

MY callback redirect uri should have code appended to it and is contain the params - status and code, but all I'm getting is this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are passing the `redirect_uri` to the request as that is required. It looks like in your screenshot it is blank but you may have commented it out for security reasons. If you are passing it through and it is the same url setup in the Spotify developer portal, try the same url in your browser and it should redirect you to a Spotify Authorization page.

Under Authorization Code Flow it lists all required parameters here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/